# Help splitting up a document file with product descriptions in it...

Tags: php, mysql, split

I have got a .doc file with english and chinese text in it, they are descriptions for products.. they are split apart in the doc by numbers i.e. 0001,0002,0003,0004,0005 etc etc

For example..

```
0001
技术参数
电压：AC90V-120V/220V-240V 50-60HZ
功率:400W
光源:120PCS 1W/3W LEDS
(R:30pcs，G:30pcs,B:30psc,W:30pcs)
控制通道：12通道
运行模式：主从，自走，声控，DMX512
 每颗LED的理论寿命为50000-100000时
光学透镜角度标准15度
水平扫描：540度，垂直扫描270度
可以调节扫描速度
无限的RGBW颜色混色系统
显示操作面板彩用LCD显示屏
产品尺寸：515*402*555mm
净重：19kg 毛重：21kg

TECHNICAL PARAMETER

Voltage: AC90V-120V or 200V-240V 50-60HZ
Power consumption:400W
Light source:120PCS 1W or 3W LED 
(R:30pcs，G:30pcs,B:30psc,W:30pcs)
Control mode:12HS
Operation mode: master-slave, auto movement,
Sound control: DMX 512
Each led source has an expectancy over 50000 to 100000 hours in theory 
Optical len angle:15 degrees
Level scanning:540 degrees Vertical scanning
270 degrees, speed adjustable 
Indefinite RGBW color mixing system
LCD display adopted
Product size:512*402*555mm
N.W:19kg  G.W:21kg


0002
技术参数
电压：AC100V-240V，50/60HZ 
功率：360W
光源：108颗 1/3W LED
运行模式：主从，自走，声控，DMX512
控制通道：11通道
水平扫描：540度，垂直扫描270度
高度电子调光，频闪可达1-20次/秒
均匀的RGB混色系统和彩虹效果(可加白色)
光斑角度：15度
包装尺寸：420*330*550mm
净重：10kg 毛重：13kg

TECHNICAL PARAMETER

Voltage:AC100V-240V ,50/60HZ 
Power consumption:306W
Light source:108pcs of 1/3W LED 
Operation mode master-slave, sound control,
auto movement,DMX512
Control channel:11Hs
Level scanning angle:540 degrees 
Vertical scanning angle:270degrees 
Quick electronic dimmer, strobe from 1 to 20 times/second
Smooth RGB mixing system &
Rainbow effect(can add white)
Beam angle:15 degrees
Package size :420*330*550mm
N.W:10kg  G.W:13kg




0003
技术参数
电压：AC90V-120V，200V-250V，50/60HZ
光束角：10度，15度，25度可选。
控制通道：11通道
预期使用寿命：50000小时
最低的能量消耗。
信号控制：12个标准DMX 12通道控制，独立的主从控制。
频闪：1-18次/秒
LED显示。
内置程序：内置的8个程序能被DMX控制激活。
尺寸：307*354*267mm
净重：8.7kg
符合GB7000.1-2007.GB7000.217-2008及CE标准

TECHNICAL PARAMETER
Power supply:AC100V-120V.200V-250V.50/60Hz
Angle of light beam:10。15。
25。 Are available for choice.
Control channel:11
Service life:50000 hours
The lowest power consumption
Control signal 12 Standard DMX controlling
Channels and ant channels combination
Can be sep up.
Independent master/slave control
Strobe:1-18 flash per second
Inside program: the 8 inside program can
 be activated by DMX controller
Dimensions:307*354*267mm
N.W:8.7kg
Up to CE standard. UL standard and
 GB 7000.15-2000standard
```

Any ideas of which best way to split it and put in to a database ?

Thanks

Lee

Comment: I tried that, ended up with too many pieces

Answer (score 1):

### 1. mb_split is for multibyte strings not preg_split

Use [`mb_split()` (linked to man page)](http://www.php.net/mb-split):

```
$descriptions = mb_split("/\d{4}/", $text);
```

### 2. Loop through the file

Another method of attack that possibly avoids non-multibyte safe PHP functions being run on the text and mucking up the Chinese portions:

```
$file = file('/file/path');
$descriptions = array();
$description_counter = 0;
foreach($file as $line) {
    $line = trim($line);
    if(preg_match("/^\d{4}$/", $line)) {
        $description_counter++;
    }
    $descriptions[$description_counter] .= $line . "\n";
}
print_r($descriptions);
```

Comment: does this still need to be parsed a plain text file ?? it contains chinese text

Comment: Yeah a UTF-8 plain text file will work with the second method.

Comment: Which method are you using? 1 or 2?

Comment: maybe its not true /n in the file

Comment: @Lee I have just run your sample against option 2 on my PHP command line and it works beautifully.

Comment: it must be the format of my text file ?? its obviously not true \n, can i chat with you on skype or msn or something to help me ?

Comment: @Treffynnon let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1956/discussion-between-lee-and-treffynnon)

Comment: @Lee I have fully tested option 1 against your sample and it needed some further tweaking. Please see the updated version, which works perfectly for me on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Copy text in $text and use

```
$r = preg_split("(\n\d{4}\n)", $text);
```

Comment: create your php project in UTF-8
not sure, but maybe will work

Comment: so this is just searching for single lines that have 4 characters, do i get that right ?

Comment: If you're not sure, test it. This matches 4 numbers, not just characters. `\d` is equivalent to `[0-9]`.

Comment: OK so what about the chinese text then ?? i have it all in a word doc but when i save it to text it goes to question marks... i need to get it all split and in to database rows...

Comment: To help with the encoding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248532/get-source-code-with-chinese-characters-php

Comment: @sukinsan see [mb_split()](http://www.php.net/mb-split) for the correct implementation of this.

Comment: $r = preg_split("(\n\d{4}\n)", $string);
echo "<pre>";
print_r ($r);

This won't split by lines that have 0002,0003 etc etc